# Execute JavaScript in a modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have the following JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function () {  
        var items = "<option value='0'>Select</option>";  
        $('#DistrictID').html(items);  
    });  
</script>
```

This populate a dropdownlist with the value Select, the thing is, this dropdownlist appears in a form that it's called once the user clicks a button and then a modal windows opens, with the form in it.

But since it is mark as

```
$(document).ready
```

This JS won't execute with the modal, since the document is already 'ready'. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Regards,

Comment: Why can't you put the code you need in a function and call that when the modal is initialized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily achieve this using bootstrap modal events. You can use following code snippet to achieve your objective:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
     $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
            var items = "<option value='0'>Select</option>";  
            $('#DistrictID').html(items); 
      });
});
```

For reference Please check [bootstrap modal events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Question tho, why you included and (e) after the word function? What is it purpose?

Comment: `e` is event data. which contains information about which element triggered this event and number of other things.

Comment: Thanks! I have a question about this code in this post. If you could check it and give me a hand I'd really appreciate it, maybe you have the answer! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45126066/javascript-modal-it-wont-trigger-on-the-first-time?noredirect=1#comment77234762_45126066

Comment: Let me see what I can do

Answer (score 0):

A useful way to **load and execute javascript after the page is loaded**, like modal window show ups, is to use ajax getScript function, which Loads (and executes) a JavaScript from a server using an AJAX HTTP GET request through a pre-defined function in main page.

```
function loadJS(lnk){
    $.getScript(lnk);
}
```

it can be a general way to load any script in a fully loaded page.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use jQuery event.on
from this blog post https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/15/how-to-implement-a-crud-using-ajax-and-json.html

I will quote the author, because I think it's a very neat explanation.

> We can’t register a listener to an element that doesn’t exists.
>
> A work around is to register the listener to an element that will
> always exist in the page context. The #modal-book is the closest
> element. It is a little bit more complex what happen, but long story
> short, the HTML events propagate to the parents elements until it
> reaches the end of the document.

More here: https://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score -2):

Try something like this:

```
$('#idofselectelement').change(function() {  
    //grab the selected option and then do what you want with it.
});
```