# Javascript & Modal. It won't trigger on the first time

Tags: javascript, asp.net, bootstrap-modal

I have an Index page with a button that calls a partial view called _Create, shown as a modal.

In the Index view I have my JScript that populates a dropdownlist on the modal. This is the code:

```
@section scripts{
<script src="~/js/store-index.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#modal-action-store').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
            var test = "#StoreArea";
            if ($(test).val()) {

            } else {
                var items = "<option value='0'>Select</option>";
                $('#DistrictID').html(items);
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#modal-action-store').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $('#DepartmentID').change(function () {
            var url = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "Stores/GetDistrict";
            var ddlsource = "#DepartmentID";
            $.getJSON(url, { DepartmentID: $(ddlsource).val() }, function (data) {
                var items = '';
                $("#DistrictID").empty();
                $.each(data, function (i, district) {
                    items += "<option value='" + district.value + "'>" + district.text + "</option>";
                });
                $('#DistrictID').html(items);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

}

**Problem:** The problem is that the first time I open the modal, the JS won't fire. I need to close the modal and open it again in order to trigger those JScripts and I'm not sure why. I tought using 'shown.bs.modal' would be enough to trigger them once the modal pops up.

Can anyone give me any feedback on this?

Thanks in advance

**Update**

This is the Index page which has declared the modal:

```
@model IEnumerable<Application.Models.Store>
@using Application.Models
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h2>Stores</h2>

<div class="top-buffer"></div>
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading panel-head">Stores</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <a id="createEditStoreModal" data-toggle="modal" asp-action="Create" data-target="#modal-action-store"
           class="btn btn-primary">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>  Add Store
            </a>
    </div>
    <div class="top-buffer"></div>
</div>
```

And this is the PartialView _Create (modal) view:

```
@model Application.Models.ApplicationviewModels.StoreIndexData
@using Application.Models


<form asp-action="Create" role="form">

<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
<div class="modal-body form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="DepartmentID" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select asp-for="DepartmentID" class="form-control"
                    asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.ListofDepartment,"DepartmentID","DepartmentName"))"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">District</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select class="form-control" id="DistrictID" name="DistrictID" asp-for="DistrictID"
                    asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.ListofDistrict,"DistrictID","DistrictName"))"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="StoreChainID" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select asp-for="StoreChainID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ChainList"></select>
            <span asp-validation-for="StoreChainID" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="StoreName" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="StoreName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="StoreName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="StoreAddress" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="StoreAddress" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="StoreAddress" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="StoreArea" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="StoreArea" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="StoreArea" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    @await Html.PartialAsync("_ModalFooter", new ModalFooter { })
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please show the code that initialises and shows the modal.

Comment: @BennyJohansson Update added!

Comment: Verify that each line using `$('#modal-action-store')` actually matches an element the first time the scripts execute.

Comment: How could I verify that? that it matches an element the first time it executes? Sorry, I'm very new at JS ):

Comment: I highly recommend that you invest time into learning these debugging techniques: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/ and https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-write. Both can be used to verify that the element is present at execution time.

Comment: Can you add me on skype (`zeshan_iqbal1`)?. Need to look closer on your code.